# Algorithm about exponential modularization

Tags: algorithm

Given integer *y*, *e*, and *p*.
How do you find *m* in *y=m<sup>e</sup> (* mod  *p)*?

This is a question in my practice midterm I cant seem to figure this out because of the exponent.

If it helps gcd(*e*,*p*-1) = 1.

Comment: The answer may not be unique because of `mod`.

Comment: http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=73708 so in general it is not easy

Comment: No, it's pretty easy.

Comment: @user2357112 maybe if e has an inverse mod p-1, an additional piece of information that was not to be found in the original question. Any thoughts on an "easy" way to solve the general modular nth root problem?

Comment: Show us your own effort to solve the problem as well please. Don't expect to just drop homework questions here and have them answered without showing what you have tried so far. And don't leave out important information.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming p is prime, we can solve the problem as follows. Compute the inverse d of e (mod p-1) using the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), then compute

```
y^d (mod p)
```

We then have

```
y^d = m^(de) (mod p)
    = m^(k*(p-1)+1) (mod p) for some integer k
    = m (mod p)
```

since if m != 0 mod p, we have `m^(p-1) = 1 (mod p)` by Fermat's little theorem, and if m = 0 (mod p), m^anything = 0 = m (mod p)

Comment: Fermat's little theorem can only be applied if p is prime.

Comment: @NiklasB.: It's pretty clearly meant to be prime. I can expand the answer with an explicit list of the details that need to be assumed to flesh out the problem.

Comment: I agree with you that it's probably meant to be prime. Still, as stated, without p being prime and without anyinformation about e, this is a hard problem. We should make OP aware that he/she is wasting our time by asking questions with lacking information like this. The question shows no signs of research effort as well, so I'm generally very judgemental about it

Comment: We do have gcd(e, p-1) = 1, though.

Comment: Not in the original version of the question.  It also doesn't make the problem easier for general p (one good hint that p is supposed to be prime and your approach is the designated one)